Convert Flat json to tree with Nested array
I'm trying convert JSON by NiFi JOLTTransformRecord processor to tree with nested array.
But I am having some trouble with converting the flat JSON to Nested JSON. I have looked at examples and didn't get any closer as to what is mentioned above. I need to transform a JSON structure by using a JOLT spec.
What I'm doing wrong?
Help Me please/
Source JSON
[
  {
    "log_date": "2024-07-24 16:10:22.851",
    "log_level": "INFO",
    "log_message": "Message1",
    "request_id": "0a3d546d"
  },
  {
    "log_date": "2024-07-24 16:10:22.851",
    "log_level": "INFO",
    "log_message": "Message2",
    "request_id": "0a3d546d"
  },
  {
    "log_date": "2024-07-24 16:10:22.851",
    "log_level": "INFO",
    "log_message": "Message3",
    "request_id": "0a3d546d"
  },
  {
    "log_date": "2024-07-24 16:10:22.572",
    "log_level": "INFO",
    "log_message": "Message4",
    "request_id": "0a3d546d"
  },
  {
    "log_date": "2024-07-24 16:10:22.572",
    "log_level": "INFO",
    "log_message": "Message5",
    "request_id": "0a3d546d"
  },
  {
    "log_date": "2024-07-24 16:10:22.572",
    "log_level": "INFO",
    "log_message": "Message6",
    "request_id": "0a3d546d"
  }
]

DESIRABLE output
{
  "request_id": "0a3d546d",
  "log": [
    {
      "log_date": "2024-07-24 16:10:22.851",
      "log_level": "INFO",
      "log_message": "Message1"
    },
    {
      "log_date": "2024-07-24 16:10:22.851",
      "log_level": "INFO",
      "log_message": "Message2"
    },
    {
      "log_date": "2024-07-24 16:10:22.851",
      "log_level": "INFO",
      "log_message": "Message3"
    },
    {
      "log_date": "2024-07-24 16:10:22.572",
      "log_level": "INFO",
      "log_message": "Message4"
    },
    {
      "log_date": "2024-07-24 16:10:22.572",
      "log_level": "INFO",
      "log_message": "Message5"
    },
    {
      "log_date": "2024-07-24 16:10:22.572",
      "log_level": "INFO",
      "log_message": "Message6"
    }
  ]
}

I'm trying use this specification
JOLT Specification
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "request_id": "request_id",
        "log*": {
          "@(1)": "log"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "request_id": "ONE"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "logs": {
        "log_date;log_level;log_message": "ONE"
      }
    }
  }
]


You might prefer using a single shift transformation spec in which the indexes of the array are matched for the ones with zero vs. others such as
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "0": {
        "request_id": "&",//only keep this value
        "*": "log[&1].&"//replicate these values arraywise with key "log"
      },
      "*": {//objects of the array with indexes other than zero
        "request_id": { "": "" },//match with empty matching in order to get rid of the extra "request_id" values
        "*": "log[&1].&"
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

If the sorting of the elements within the result JSON matters, then add an extra little spec :
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "request_id|log": "&"
    }
  }

so as to get :
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "0": {
        "request_id": "&",
        "*": "log[&1].&"
      },
      "*": {
        "request_id": { "": "" },
        "*": "log[&1].&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "request_id|log": "&"
    }
  }
]

